# Unknown Xeon processor model

Tags: 14.04, drivers, server

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm trying to get the model number of a IBM server I found. I'm trying to see what model Xeons it has. The conventional methods aren't working for me. Here's what if done.

**Q1:** What Processor models are these CPUs? Please. Am I correct in saying it could be [this processor on ARK](http://ark.intel.com/products/27088/64-bit-Intel-Xeon-Processor-3_60-GHz-1M-Cache-800-MHz-FSB)?

**Q2:** Are there any specific drivers I need to download for this platform to run Ubuntu Server? This is a clean install ontop of a HW RAID config LVM.

Here's the [FULL LSHW](http://pastebin.com/1YkE91EY) report on pastebin.

So, from opening the chassis I know it has 2 physical Xeons, and 8GB RAM *(strange 2x2GB, 2x1GB en 4x512MB RAM modules config)*

**The Cats in /proc/cpuinfo**

```
dev@teamserver:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep CPU
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.60GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.60GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.60GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.60GHz
dev@teamserver:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep process
processor   : 0
processor   : 1
processor   : 2
processor   : 3
dev@teamserver:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep 'name'| uniq
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.60GHz
dev@teamserver:~$
```

**...from lshw**

```
dev@teamserver:~$ sudo lshw | head
teamserver                
    description: System
    product: eserver xSeries 346 -[8840EHY]-
    vendor: IBM
    serial: KDPLTV7
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.3 dmi-2.3 vsyscall32
    configuration: chassis=server uuid=FA66A32B-EF1D-B211-A01D-D19AA860369E


dev@teamserver:~$ sudo lshw | grep -i cpu
     *-cpu:0
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.60GHz
          bus info: cpu@0
          slot: Socket 1 CPU 1
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx x86-64 constant_tsc pebs bts nopl pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 cid cx16 xtpr lahf_lm cpufreq
     *-cpu:1
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.60GHz
          bus info: cpu@1
          slot: Socket 2 CPU 2
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx x86-64 constant_tsc pebs bts nopl pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 cid cx16 xtpr lahf_lm cpufreq
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try using cpuid, this provides more information.

to install it open a terminal and issue the command `sudo apt-get install cpuid` then `cpuid` to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name"`